# How can I return an empty response from a class?

Tags: java

```
public DataRule getRule(){
     * code logic *
return null;
}
```

Instead of return null, how can I return an empty response? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Use `Optional.empty()`. https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional

Comment: But then for that, I will have to make the method datatype optional, I want to be able to return an empty response without changing the datatype

Comment: return new DataRule(); //But Depend on what you mean by empty response, it should only return class DataRule. or you mean return  an empty object/ parent class of DataRule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options to return "no rule" from your method `getRule()`.

The first and most simple way is, as you did already, to return `null`, but you want to avoid that.

Next is to try `java.util.Optional`, as Nikolai Shevchenko suggested in his comment:

```
public Optional<DataRule> getRule()
{
  Optional<DataRule> retValue = Optional.empty();

  /*
   * Add some code here that determines a DataRule instance.
   */
  retValue = new Optional.of( new DataRule() ); // for example …

  return retValue;
}
```

Depending on the internal structure of `DataRule`, you can have an "empty rule", analog to an empty String: `final String EMPTY_STRING = "";`. This may look like this:

```
public static final DataRule EMPTY_RULE = … // Create an empty instance of DataRule

…

public DataRule getRule()
{
  var retValue = EMPTY_RULE;

  /*
   * Add some code here that determines a DataRule instance.
   */
  retValue = new DataRule(); // for example …

  return retValue;
}

var dataRule = getRule();
if( dataRule == EMPTY_RULE )
{
  …
}
else
{
  …
}
```

The comparison with `==` works if you will always use the same `EMPTY_RULE` instance, otherwise you need to use `if( rule.equals( EMPTY_RULE ) ) …`.

Comment: This should be a comment, rather than an answer. You don't describe or list any of the possibilities you talk about.

Comment: @Stultuske – You was not patient enough

Comment: There's a `;` missing at `var retValue = EMPTY_RULE`.

Comment: @Izruo – Fixed! Thx for the headsup!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pick one: either return a null and check for that, or return Optional<DataRule> and check isEmpty().  The current best practice is to return Optional<DataRule> as that means that consumers of the method result have to consciously handle the possibility that no value is returned, whereas a null check is a kind of implicit "no value" value.  The problem is that sometimes "null" means "no value", and sometimes it means something else, so it's ambiguous.